CoreGraphics.CGFloat errors after updating XCode to version 16
I recently updated my mac to version 15.0 (Sequoia) so I was forced to update Xcode to version 16, since then I am having the following errors to build the project

Steps I took to try and resolve the errors:

exclude architecture arm64
Deleted and reinstalled the node_modules folder.
Deleted the Pods folder and Podfile.lock.
Ran pod install.
Cleared the Derived Data folder.
Cleaned the build.
Rebuilt the project.
added config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"


In addition to the duplicate question (make sure to search before posting), please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

i am also facing sam isseu

Did you fix it?
